# php-curl times out when calling a php on the same domain

Tags: php-curl

I do have a very strange problem where I cannot find any way for debugging. I have a server running Arch Linux, Apache 2.4 and PHP versions 7.4, 8.0 and recent 8.1 as php-fpm. All PHP configurations are identically (modules and configs). But 8.1 has a very strange behaviour regarding php-curl.

I install this php (curltest.php) on my server:

```
<?php
// this was the originally intended code:
// define ('HTTP_URL', 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/curltest.php?test=1');

// this doeas not work, too:
define ('HTTP_URL', 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/any_php_script.php');

// all commented following lines are for testing if $_GET is the cause
// if (empty($_GET['test'])) {
        $curlHandle = curl_init();

        $fp = fopen('/tmp/error.txt', 'w+');

        curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, array(
                CURLOPT_URL            => HTTP_URL,
                CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
                CURLOPT_STDERR         => $fp,
                CURLOPT_FAILONERROR    => false,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 5,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curlHandle);

        if (curl_errno($curlHandle)) {
                $response =  'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curlHandle);
       }

        curl_close($curlHandle);
//} else {
        $response = 'Erfolg';
//}

echo $response;
```

The script works perfectly if I run it with PHP 7.4 and 8.0. If I use PHP8.1 I get a "timeout" - no response, nothing in the logs. I dug a bit deeper and tested with calling a text or html file instead of the script itself: this works flawlessly. If I call another php on the same domain the issue pops up again. But if I call a php on the same server but a different domain it works! So the problem only exists:

- when using PHP 8.1 (8.1.13-1)
- calling a php script which resides on the same domain as my testscript
  So it cannot be a dns issue (calling text or html files is working). And it cannot be a problem that I cannot access php via a php-curl: using different domain (on the same server running the same php version) is also working. Any hint for debugging this is welcome.

As already stated I tested with different file types and different domains (on the same server using the same php version). I increased php log level and activated curl to be verbose writing STDERR to file output without success.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting a timeout because you are running in an endless loop. It looks like in that one setup the `$_GET` variable is not populated and so the if condition always evaluates to true, opening another curl request.

The reason for this can be a misconfiguration of `variables_order` (php.ini) or FPM parameters (sometimes in a file like `fastcgiparams` or `fastcgi_param` params in nginx).

You can verify this by putting a small message after opening the error log:

```
fwrite($fp, 'Opening socket ' . (string)$curlHandle . PHP_EOL);
```

Make sure you got `G` in `ini_get('variables_order');`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I have removed $_GET variable completely from script and behaviour is the same, so this is not the reason...

Comment: @DF8OE the problem seems not reproducible, can you update the code in question and provide some debug steps

Comment: @DF8OE the new code is an infinite loop again, the timeout is because the script is calling itself over and over again

Comment: "Infinite loop" is not the cause of the issue. Please take a look at the editied code above.